# Sending Java GET parameters to the server (witout hanging)

Tags: java, http, urlconnection

I would like to send a GET parameter to a server.   I really do not need the InputStream (below), but the request is actually sent when I call "getInputStream".  The problem is, this code hangs on getInputStream.  The timeout does not apply because the connection is actually established (does not time-out).

What do I need to change so that I'm sending a clean GET to the server without hanging?

```
URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8888/abc?message=abc"); //[edit]
URLConnection uc = url.openConnection();
uc.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8");
uc.setConnectTimeout(1000);
InputStream in = uc.getInputStream();
in.close();
```

In case it matters, I'm testing with `netcat -l` as the server instead of using an actual web server.  None the less, I would like this code to be very fail-safe so it the server can't adversely effect this code.

Comment: Try `uc.connect()` instead of getInputStream()? Not sure what's causing the hangups though.

Comment: `uc.connect()` does not seem to make the connection (netcat does not display anything).  The data is transfered and shown in netcat when I call getInputStream.  I believe it is hanging because neither side closes the connection.  It is blocking waiting for input from netcat.  My intent is just to pass the GET parameters and close the connection (in the same thread).

Answer (score 0):

I basically gave up in using the URLConnection and wrote the code to use a socket instead.  I'm still open for improvements, light-weight posting to a web server is very useful.

```
        URL u = new URL("http://localhost:8888/abc?message=abc");
        String get = "";
        if (u.getPath() != null)
            get += u.getPath();
        if (u.getQuery() != null)
            get += "?" + u.getQuery();
        if (u.getRef() != null)
            get += "#" + u.getRef();

        Socket socket = new Socket();
        socket
                .connect(new InetSocketAddress(u.getHost(), u.getPort()),
                        750);

        OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();
        out.write(("GET " + get + "\n\n").getBytes());
        out.close();
```